# Twitter Card Preview is failing with twitter:image

Tags: twitter, meta-tags, twitter-card

I'm trying to add [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/preview) to my site so that tweets referencing my blog posts will be expandable and show extra info.

When I include a `twitter:image` tag, the Twitter Card fails, but when I remove it, it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
<meta property="twitter:url" content="http://liberalgeek.com/content/why-do-atheists-celebrate-christmas" />
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta property="twitter:description" content="I can&#039;t speak for all atheists, I can only speak for myself, so please leave a comment below and explain why you celebrate Christmas! When I hear someone ask, &quot;Why do atheists celebrate Christmas?&quot; my first thought often is: Better Question: Why do Christians celebrate Christmas?" />
<meta property="twitter:creator" content="@kennywyland" />
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Why do Atheists celebrate Christmas?" />

<!-- the following line causes the problem -->
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://liberalgeek.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/Christmas%20Tree.jpg" />
```

The image is publicly visible, it's large enough without being too large... what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://liberalgeek.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/Christmas%20Tree.jpg" />
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator

Comment: I think this answer might've become outdated. According to the information here (https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-image-src-or-twitter-image/16085), both are fine at this time but the recommended way is using `twitter:image`.

Answer (score 0):

Change robots.txt to allow robots to visit your site.